# How do we determine if a function is linear?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, linear-transformations, determinant

I've been dealing with a question for 2-3 days. I hope you can help. I solved some of it but I don't know if it's right? and I don't know what to do with the rest. You can find my question and solution suggestion below. have a nice day

Question;

a) **f:R2→R,(x1,x2)→x1⋅x2**

b) **f:R2→R3,(x1,x2)→(2x1,−x2,x1+x2)**

C) **f:R2→R,(x1,x2)→⟨(α,β),(x1,x2)⟩  (α,β∈R fixed)**

1. f(0)=0
2. is f(v1+v2)=f(v1)+f(v2)
3. is f(rv)=rf(v) with v=(x1,x2)

**Also for** 1)

f(0)=0 skalar α=0

x=(x1,x2),y=(y1,y2)∈R2 and ∀  α,β∈K.

αx+βy=(αx1+βy1,αx2+βy2)

**Then**

f(αx+βy)=f(αx1+βy1,αx2+βy2)

=(αx1+βy1)(αx2+βy2)

=α2x1x2+αβ(x1y2+x2y1)+β2y1y2.

**same for** αf(x)+βf(y)

αf(x)+βf(y)=αf(x1,x2)+βf(y1,y2)

=α(x1x2)+β(y1y2)

=αx1x2+βy1y2

**When** x=(1,1)=y∈R2

**for** α=1=β∈K

f(αx+βy)=4≠2=αf(x)+βf(y)

**also not linear**

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The answer to the title question is: by using just the definition of a linear map. There is a "for all" statement, and if it is not satified "for all" elements, then it is not linear.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have proven that the function in $(a)$ is not linear by illustrating a counterexample.

Here is my alternative counterexample.

For part $(a)$, we have $f\left( \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}\right)=f\left(\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}  \right)=1\cdot 1 = 1$

which is not equal to $f\left( \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}\right) + f\left(\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}\right)=1\cdot 0 + 0\cdot 1 = 0$.

Hence they are not equal.

$b$ and $c$ are both linear. Try to verify condition $(2)$ and $(3)$ for them and update us with your attempt. Alternativly, verify that for a matrix $A$, $f_A(x)=Ax$ is linear.